# How can I intentionally let Access crash?

Tags: ms-access, registry, taskscheduler

I would like to find a way to let Access crash in such a way that when you re-open the database, you will get this popup message:

'The last time you opened "....accdb", it caused a serious error. Do you still want to open it?'

Reason for this that have to maintain a server with a lot of cronjobs that launch even more Access applications, and sometimes it happens that a crashed Access application cannot be launched anymore due to this popup which prevents opening the database until you click 'Yes'.

To test my solution (remove registry key HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Access\Resiliency\DisabledItems), I need to have an access database that crashes on request.

Is there a way to do this with a vba script?

Comment: I guess i'm missing the reason why you need it to crash vs close via vba code. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Hi Pants, no there is no good reason, I think it is based on the assumption that this best can be done by vba script. Any other way is fine for me as well, as long as it crashes and will trigger the popup the next time I open it.

Comment: Heh, I have never seen this message. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751048/how-to-programatically-re-enable-documents-in-the-ms-office-list-of-disabled-fil -- from there it seems you're on the right track.

Comment: The easiest way to accomplish this would be to programmatically write a value to a "error table" then close the application. When you open the database just write another vba script to read the value in that table, then display a messagebox if a record or specific "error" exists in the table.

Comment: Hi Pants, I'm not fully sure, but I don't think your approach will cause Access to really crash, meaning that the application freezes and killing it is the task manager it he only way out. @Andre, yes that is the message. Sadly they don't give an example of how to get an document/database 'on that list' as well...

Answer (score 0):

Write a script that kills the running process.

Comment: Hi Cocofalco, I tried that with the code found here: https://www.devhut.net/2015/05/28/ms-access-vba-kill-a-process/ . It obviously closes the app, and the lockfile stays. But when I open it again, I don't get the popup sadly.