# Skip error "The document caused a serious error the last time it was opened"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Is it possible to skip error "The document caused a serious error the last time it was opened"? I use Excel to opening Word files. I would like to prevent situation, when e.g. pc reboots while running macro, and later Word thinks there is problem with file. But I am always sure that my template files are OK (I use read-only method). Skip means selecting "Yes" with VBA to continue opening file. Setting display alerts to false is not working. Thanks!

```
 Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 With wApp
         .DisplayAlerts = False
         .Visible = False
         .ScreenUpdating = False
 End With
```

**Edit:** 
I just found that the only way seems to be editing registry:
[How to programatically re-enable documents in the MS Office list of disabled files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751048/how-to-programatically-re-enable-documents-in-the-ms-office-list-of-disabled-fil)
Unfortunately I can't modify registry by macro because of IT security managment in a company.

**Edit2:** 
I've posted workaround below

Comment: This is helpful workaround. I am using a C# library that uses word.interop dll (COM) and no matter what I've tried whenever I save a file with the library it says there is a critical error when trying to open it next time... nothing wrong with the file. It appears to be an issue with using the COM library to modify documents. Even just opening a document with the library and closing with no changes causes the serious error warning.

Answer (score 2):

I found not elegant, but really easy workaround to a problem. In the Windows registry there is a "blacklist" (called *disabled list*) containing files, that Office finds problematic when last time opened. The workaround is to change the name of our file for a moment instead of deleting entries in the system's registry.

Sample code for beginners would be more clear than description, I think:

```
' folder's path
  Dim fPath As String:     fPath = "D:\templates\"
' Word file to open
  Dim fName As String:     fName = "sample.docx"

  Dim fullFilePath As String
      fullFilePath =  fPath & fName

' temporary name
' I use here idea to add unique timestamp prefix
  Dim tempName As String
      tempName = VBA.Strings.Format(Now(), "yyMMdd_hhmmss_") & fName

  Dim fullTempFilePath As String
      fullTempFilePath =  fPath & tempName 

' temporary change
  Name fullFilePath As fullTempFilePath 

  Dim wApp as object ' late binding
  Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Set doc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=fullTempFilePath)

 ' here some code to file manipulate
 ' ...
  doc.Close

 ' restore previous file name
  Name fullTempFilePath As fullFilePath 

 ' end 
  wApp.Quit
  Set wApp = Nothing
```

I would add some error handling to make sure the previous file name will be restored. If someone see a better idea, feel free to share here.

Answer (score -1):

This problem occurs because the file is included in the list of disabled files for the Microsoft Office program. The program adds a file to this list if the file causes a serious error, such as causing the program to close unexpectedly (crash) during two or more attempts to open it. This error message lets you avoid potential problems that may occur if you open the file.

I'd suggest disabling add-ins. To do this, follow these steps:

1. In Excel or Word, click `File`, click `Options`, and then click `Add-Ins`.
2. In the Manage list, click `COM Add-Ins`, and then click `Go`.
3. In the `COM Add-Ins` dialog box, clear the check box for any one of the add-ins in the list that's selected, and then click `OK`.
4. Restart the application (not in safe mode).

If the program starts successfully, the add-in for which you cleared the check box is the one that's causing the problem. If the program doesn't start after you complete these steps, repeat these steps by clearing the check box for a different add-in.

If the program doesn't start after you have tested all the listed add-ins, the problem isn't related to the add-ins. To learn about other reasons why this may problem may occur, go to the "References" section.

If the problematic add-in is a third-party product, we recommend that you go to the company website to get a newer version of the add-in. If there's no newer version available or if you don't have to use the add-in, you can leave that check box cleared in the COM Add-Ins list.

Read more about that in the ["The document caused a serious error the last time it was opened" when you open a file in Excel or Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/opening-file-cause-error) article.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "Unexpectedly (crash) during two or more attempts" - it isn't true, one fail is enough to add file to disabled list. COM Add-Ins aren't problem too. I've just updated question- it seems the only way is to registry editing.