# How to fix error while working with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: ms-word, office-interop

I am writing a simple Winforms app to generate 44 separate letters from a MS Word template. I get data to each letter from a local SQL Server database. While running the generate letters method I get the error shown here randomly. I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to do this:

[image]

> The last time you opened x.docx, it caused a serious error. Do you still want to open it?

When I click No the program exits and when clicked Yes it continues. I manually re-enabled the file in Word options -  Add-ins, and I have read solutions about registry editing and questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62189590/skip-error-the-document-caused-a-serious-error-the-last-time-it-was-opened/62190260#62190260).

Why does this happen, and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: On might ask why you're not simply automating a mailmerge for this...

Comment: actually the database contains person data from which i am going generate several reports each month. we add, delete or modify data every month. the letters contain payment lists of people which are sent to 44 different offices in the area. can I query data from the database each month to use in mail merge? Thanks for reminding about mail merge

Comment: «can I query data from the database each month to use in mail merge?» Indeed one can.